# How to submit an exisitng object from the view via a from in Thymeleaf with Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

In my Thymeleaf view, I have some objects shown on the page:
[image]
Here's the HTML

```html
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="@{/basket}" th:object="${itemOrder}">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">
            <a href="#" class="item-title" th:text="${item.title}">item title</a>
        </h4>
        <h5 th:text="${item.price} + ' €'">item price</h5>
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{sku}"/> <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" />
    </div>
</form>
<div class="container" th:if="${itemOrder != null}">
    <h4>Item in the basket:</h4><br>
    <h5 th:text="${itemOrder.price} + ' €'">item price</h5>
</div>
```

Under each element, I have a form to submit this element to the controller.
All Thymeleaf and Spring MVC guides are showing how to submit a form when a user provides data through `input` fields. Here, I don't need to take in any data from the user, all the data is available already. I just need to wrap existing data and submit it with a form. How can I make it with Thymeleaf and Spring MVC?

Here's the BasketController that should handle the form reu

```java
@PostMapping("/basket")
public String processItemOrder(@ModelAttribute ItemOrder itemOrder, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("itemOrder", itemOrder);
    return "basket";
}
```

Comment: You do it with hidden fields, just like you are doing... what's the problem?

Comment: @Metroids if I add `th:text="${item.sku}"` or `th:value="${item.sku}" to the hidden input from above, then it's not binded. The field is empty.

Comment: You are using `th:object="${itemOrder}"`. So, does `itemOrder` have a `sku` field? Otherwise `th:field="*{sku}"` will not work. Your previous comment suggests you are mixing up `${itemOrder}` with `${item}` - and maybe it is actually `item` that has the `sku` field, not `itemOrder`. But we cannot know for sure - that information is missing from the question.

Comment: @andrewJames, both `Item` and `ItemOrder` classes have the `sku` field. I'm presenting the `Item` object in the view and then want to map it to the `ItemOrder` and send it via a form. I can't understand now how can I present in the view `Item`'s fields so that those would be mapped to the `ItemOrder` in the form.

Comment: Use `th:object="${item}"`. Send the clicked item to the server upon form submission. Add that submitted item to the order (the basket) on the server.

Comment: It seems to me that an order should be a collection of `item`s, not a collection of `itemOrder`s.

Comment: @andrewJames I changed to `th:object="${item}"` and also changed the basket controller from `ItemOrder` to `Item` but it's still `null` in the basket controller...

Comment: OK - thank you for trying that, anyway. Sorry, I don't see the problem. I assume if you changed `${item.price}` to `${item.sku}` (just to test) then you would see the SKU being displayed OK in the web page.

Comment: I guess it may be your use of `@ModelAttribute` - maybe you need `@RequestBody` there to get the POST response data?

Comment: @andrewJames I think I found a way how to sort it out. Thanks to this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517040/6934058 I'm passing just a single field - `sku` and changing the basket controller to accept the sku as a `@RequestParam`.